# Is possible for Jenkins to auto start and stop slave nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops

I have a Jenkins master in my network with a slave node.
I am planning to create another node in AWS EC2, a big expensive server.
I would like to have a single Jenkins build that:

1. Jenkins Master starts slave node.
2. Jenkins node runs the script.
3. Jenkins Master stops the slave node. (I can directly execute shutdown myself)

I know I can have three separate builds to do it. I was wondering if **is possible to have this in one build only?**
Is there any plugin(s) that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never used it, but [Amazon EC2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) should do the trick.

Comment: Updated link to one that doesn't require login. Seems interesting... thanks. I will investigate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Jenkins Plugin called as Slave SetupPlugin

> https://plugins.jenkins.io/slave-setup
>
> https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/58002132/68747470733a2f2f676f6c6466697368746970732e66696c65732e776f726470726573732e636f6d2f323031362f30362f746e63686a716e74766a2e706e67.png?version=1&modificationDate=1467444498000&api=v2

Comment: Could you add an explanation why one should choose this approach?